# Firebase cloud functions error (TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined)

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I have a simple cloud function running on the functions emulator:

```
exports.helloFirebase = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return "Hello"
})
```

When I call it from my firebase app, as follows...

```
export default {
    helloFirebase: httpsCallable(fucntions, "helloFirebase")
}
```

then...

```
functionsObj.helloFirebase()
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("ERROR IN FUNCTIONS")
        console.log(error.message)
    })
```

I get an error in my cloud functions console:

```
!  functions: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at processBackground (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase- 
    tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:550:24)
    at invokeTrigger (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase- 
    tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:640:19)
    at handleMessage (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase- 
    tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:742:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
!  Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.
```

I've tried everything to solve this issue and it's still not working. Is this a bug in the firebase admin SDK?

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue with version `10.3.1` of firebase tools.
[Here's](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4313) the GitHub issue.

You can fix this quickly by running:

```
npm update -g firebase-tools
```

Comment: I have the same problem, however the update didn't help. I upgraded `firebase-tools` both in project and globally to **11.9.0** and the issue still persists on local emulation.